# How to print the current post depth as update notification?

Tags: functions, children

I need to find a simple if-condition to print the current post-depth for parents as an update notification. The following code in the functions.php is not working, it is resulting in "0" for all posts, both for parents and childs. Can anybody help out on this?

```
global $wpdb;
global $post;
$id = $post->ID;
$depth = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_parent FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = '".$id."'");
if($depth == '0')
    {
function my_admin_notice() {
    ?>
    <div class="updated">
        <p><?php _e( 'Depth is 0!', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );
}
```

Comment: As @MortalViews mentioned, do you definitely need the depth of the post, or just check if it has a parent or not?

Comment: You should really start accepting answers that solved your problem. Questions with no accepted answers get recycled radomly over and over by the system. This blocks questions that really needs a solution to be recycled. To accept an answer, check on the left hand side of the answer is a check mark just below the up/down arrow. Click on that. The arrow will turn green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your condition inside the function, rather than the function inside the condition (this will also prevent errors with code running too early as WordPress loads).

```
function my_admin_notice() {
    global $wpdb, $post;

    $depth = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_parent FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d", $post->ID )
    );

    if ( $depth == '0' ) : ?>

    <div class="updated">
        <p><?php _e( 'Depth is 0!', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>

    <?php
    endif;
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to query for post parent id, when you already have the post object.

You can access the parent id directly:

```
$parent_id =  $post->post_parent;
```

But since your intention is to get the 'depth' of the page, you need to add a loop until you reach the main parent.of the current page to calculate the depth.

**Code example:**

```
function my_admin_notice() {
    global $post;

    $parent_id = $post->post_parent;
    $depth = 0;
    while ($parent_id > 0) {
        $parent = get_post($parent_id);
        $parent_id = $parent->post_parent;
        $depth++;
    }
    ?>

    <div class="updated">
        <p><?php _e("Depth is {$depth}! ", 'my-text-domain'); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action('admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice');
```

Comment: Good point, and one I failed to address in my answer.